# Editing Hyperlinks(x).texttodisplay moves hyperlink to beginning of text box in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I'm having problems with VBA in PowerPoint - when I try to edit the TextToDisplay property of a hyperlink, it edits the text, but moves the hyperlink location to the beginning of the text box.

[image: broken hyperlinks]

On the first pass, I get the first characters of the text box changed into the link, then on the second pass, that link gets rewritten.

I'm using the following code to update the page numbers of hyperlinks when slides get moved around.

```
Sub UpdatePageNumbers()

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For x = CInt(sld.Hyperlinks.Count) To 1 Step -1
        strParts = Split(sld.Hyperlinks(x).SubAddress, ",")
        PageNumber = ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(CInt(strParts(0))).SlideNumber
        sld.Hyperlinks(x).TextToDisplay = "Page " & PageNumber
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Has anyone seen this before/come up with a solution? Had a search and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can repro the odd behavior. This may work better for you.  I've changed it to explicitly DIM all variables (good practice in general), and used Longs rather than Integers, since that's what PPT uses internally.  Next, apparently changing the Displayed Text also changes or deletes the hyperlink (sometimes but not always?  weird!).  That throws off your loop counter.  So instead, for each hyperlink I've stored its subaddress, made any changes to the text, then reapplied the subaddress afterward.

```
Sub UpdatePageNumbers()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim x As Long
Dim strParts
Dim PageNumber As Long
Dim oHl As Hyperlink
Dim oTxtRange As TextRange
Dim sSubaddress As String

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    'For x = CLng(sld.Hyperlinks.Count) To 1 Step -1
    For Each oHl In sld.Hyperlinks
        With oHl
            sSubaddress = .SubAddress
            strParts = Split(.SubAddress, ",")
            PageNumber = ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(CLng(strParts(0))).SlideNumber
            'oHl.TextToDisplay = "Page " & PageNumber
            Set oTxtRange = .Parent.Parent
            oTxtRange.Text = "Page " & PageNumber
            oTxtRange.ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.SubAddress = sSubaddress
        End With
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Steve - it seems to work! Spent a while on this before asking the question - it was just seemed really odd that it was moving the hyperlink text to the front of the text box, yet editing the hyperlink correctly.

Comment: Glad it's working for you ... as to exactly why it was behaving the way it was, a confluence of things, I suspect.

Comment: Note that this solution is not quite equivalent to setting TextToDisplay.  If you create a hyperlink without explicitly setting TextToDisplay, then place the cursor immediately after the hyperlink and begin typing, the added text will be hyperlinked.  This is likely undesirable in many cases.

Comment: To be more specific, this occurs when the hyperlink is at the end of a paragraph.